# AttributeError in cython wrapper for python error

Tags: python, cython

I have created a C++ wrapper in cython for python.

The C++ class has the method name makeBooleanValue, but in python I want the equivalent method to be make_boolean_value.

But I am getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "saxon_example.py", line 7, in 
>       xdmAtomicval = proc.make_boolean_value(False)
>   AttributeError: 'saxonc.PySaxonProcessor' object has no attribute 'make_boolean_value'

It seems like I cannot use a different naming convention in cython.

In the pxd file I have the following:

> XdmAtomicValue * makeBooleanValue(bool b)

In the pyx file I have the following:

> ```
> def make_boolean_value(self, b):
>     cdef bool c_b = b
>     cdef PyXdmAtomicValue val = PyXdmAtomicValue()
>     val.derivedaptr = val.derivedptr = val.thisvptr = self.thisptr.makeBooleanValue(c_b)
>     return val
> ```

But in my python example script:

```
print(dir(library))
```

I get make makeBooleanValue

Any ideas what I am missing please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the changes in the pyx file are not being picked up when I run a python  script. But it is being picked up when I run python from commandline